# Coverage tool to build good unit tests

Tags: packages-testing

**What I'm looking for...** Do it exist tools "tracking" or reporting macros and environments used when compiling one `TEX` file?

**Why?** To build my unit tests, I need to verify if my package is fully tested.

Comment: ‘No’ but I might be able to suggest something a bit later!

Comment: Will you play with some hooks?